# How to store values in Angular 2?

Tags: angularjs, angular

I have to migrate a Website from angular 1.3.x to angular 4.3.0

While going through the code i have a few questions

The application uses some kind of value

```
angular.module('abc').value('externalProviderConfigSettings', {
    settingsVersion: "2.0",
    facebook: { appKey: '', appSecret: '', redirectUrl: '', state: '', permissions: ['email', 'public_profile', 'user_friends', 'publish_actions', 'manage_pages'] },
    twitter: { appKey: '', appSecret: '', redirectUrl: '', state: '', permissions: [] },
    linkedin: { appKey: '', appSecret: '', redirectUrl: '', state: '', permissions: ['r_basicprofile', 'r_emailaddress', 'w_share', 'rw_company_admin'] },
    google: { appKey: '', appSecret: '', state: '', permissions: [] },
    pinterest: { redirectUrl: '' }
});
```

How to migrate these kind of value in Angular 4.3.0.
I'm going through the documentation but not able to figure out.
Similarly there is a .config code

```
angular.module('abc').config
```

How to handle that in angular 2?
Its a big app and i want make sure that my approach is correct.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a service to handle app-wide reachable state: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to export a const and then import it wherever you want, for example:

**environment/environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  token_auth_config: {
    apiBase: 'http://localhost:3000',
    signInRedirect: '/login'
  }
};
```

Then in any other file you import it

```
import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

this.authToken.init(environment.token_auth_config);
```